# TCP from android to PC not working using java

Tags: java, android, tcp

I am trying to send a simple message over `TCP` from my android phone (using java application) to my computer. I have an socket that is listening on my computer but as soon as I run this app, it crashes. I am really new to Android developing so please bear with me...

**Here is my Java code:**

```
package com.scorekeep.clienttcp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText textOut;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("10.0.0.10",5000);
            DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            DOS.writeUTF("HELLO_WORLD");
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the code of your Server? What crashes exactly ? The server or the client?

Comment: The client/android app crashes. @NicolasFilotto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested an extended example :

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new connection().execute();
    }
}

 class connection extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
public static PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;
public static boolean running = true;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... message) {

        try
        {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8008);
            // send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                              new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    socket.getInputStream()));

        while(running) {
            String msgfromserver = in.readLine();
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}

        return null;
    }

    public static void sendmsg(String msg){
        if(out!=null){
            out.println(msg);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**
Call `connection.sendmsg("some text");` from OnClick method of button

And set `connection.running = false;` onbackpress. (Or before finishing activity)

Comment: One problem, when adding the `connection.sendmsg("some text")` the editor gives error and tells met to make sendmsg static. How do I fix this? Error: `Error:(22, 19) error: non-static method sendmsg(String) cannot be referenced from a static context`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute background tasks like socket connection in ui thread. You should use AsyncTask.

**Example**

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new connection().execute();
    }
}

class connection extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... message) {

        try
        {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("ip here");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 5000); //port here
    // send the message to the server
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                              new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        out.println("hi");
        out.flush(); //optional
        socket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Note** Untested. May contain errors.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? @user6657161

Comment: Wait i am coding an example for you.

Comment: Thanks @user6657161

Comment: Thanks, the example works. Could you maybe just show me how I could send a message to the server each time a button is pressed without closing and opening the server each time.

Answer (score 1):

Two changes in code. `public static void sendmsg` and public `public static PrintWriter out` at begining of AsyncTask class

Comment: Added it as answer by mistake.

Comment: I can't delete my answer as i am on android. Alas!