# continuous message receiving asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am making a chat application.The server will send me an update whenever a friend sends me a message.As a result i need a continuous listener from my android client.I have used asynchronous task and in the post execute method, i have called the asynchronous task again.Thus listening continuously.But this is giving me weird errors.

If you could help me i would be really grateful.If you think i should implement the continuous listener in some other way please do suggest me.Thanks.

Comment: `in the post execute method, i have called the asynchronous task again` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper method should be like when you get connected to server, you should keep listening in a loop. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306100/tcp-from-android-to-pc-not-working-using-java)

and modify it as needed.

Comment: Accept it as answer using tick.

Answer (score 0):

What about using http://quickblox.com/developers/Android library? I am just curious, if it would not be easier :) .

Otherwise I thought about making while cycle in `doInBackground()` method, instead of calling asyncTask all over again.

Something like -

```
While(programExit) {
   //your code
}
```